# Unit test for unspecified custom objects?

Tags: unit-test, custom-object

I have a a couple of methods that take the name of a custom object as a parameter and do a dynamic SOQL search on the specified object. The methods work great, but now I'm writing the unit tests...

I know how to create test data, but can I create test custom objects?

I considered using standard objects as stand-ins for my test, but I can't find any standard objects that meet the simple criteria: I need a look-up or master-detail relationship where the name of the field matches the name of the related object. For example, I can't use Account and Opportunity because the Account field on Opportunity is called "AccountId".

I tried using Opportunity and OpportunityLineItem, but it's saying I have

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

Can anyone suggest a standard object that will meet the need? Or, do you know a way to generate a custom object within the test?

Comment: Could you explain a little better why can't you insert an Opportunity and an OpportunityLineItem, and then query for both records using your dynamic SOQL?

Comment: Is this for a method for a managed package, or for your own org?

Comment: For which object you are actually using that code. Just use same objects in test class and They will work.

Comment: Renato, I don't know why I got that error. sfdxfox -- managed package. Tushar -- this is for a managed package app that will integrate with whatever custom objects the customer might be using -- hence the need for flexibility/adaptability. I realized that for testing I can use a couple of the custom objects in my package that have the needed relationship.

Comment: Could you share an example of what you have tried that is throwing this error - possibly a stripped down version of your method ( so not to include your proprietary codes - but to still give the gist of how it is being accessed )